# Returning interfered by get documents firestore swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I've been trying to get paginated data, but for some reason, I'm not able to get this right. I did the debugging quite a few times, but with the absence of any errors it seems this is the expected behavior from Firestore getDocuments. Any help would be appreciated -> I am trying to return the posts variable from the method below

```
private var query: Query
    private var documents: [QueryDocumentSnapshot] = []

    init() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        self.query = db.collection("posts").order(by: "createdTimeStamp")
    }

    func updateQuery() -> Query{
        let nextQuery: Query
        if let lastDocument = documents.last {
            nextQuery = query.start(afterDocument: lastDocument).limit(to: 5)
        } else {
            nextQuery = query.limit(to: 5)
        }
        return nextQuery
    }

    public func fetchNext() -> [ObjectPost] {
        var posts: [ObjectPost] = []
        let updatedQuery = updateQuery()

        updatedQuery.getDocuments(completion: { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let e = error {
                print(e.localizedDescription)
            }

            guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
                print("Error fetching next documents: \(error!)")
                return
            }

            let newPosts = snapshot.documents.map { doc -> ObjectPost in
                let post = try! FirestoreDecoder().decode(ObjectPost.self, from: doc.data())
                print("post \(post.postBody)")
                return post
            }

            posts += newPosts
            print("--After posts update")
            self.documents += snapshot.documents
            print("--After documents update")
        })

        print("Before returning posts")
        return posts
    }
```

I am able to reach till "After documents update" but it never reaches "Before returning posts" and also the posts are never returned. What am I missing here?

UPDATE: 
For those reading this as a means to solve their own queries, I was missing the asynchronous nature of the Firebase APIs, which is very well explained here https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93 and here https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/07/swift-closures-and-firebase-handling.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing that the return statement is in the closure that runs asynchronously after the return from the `fetchNext` function.

See the [Firestore quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/firestore/FirestoreExample) for some examples of managing data in a closure completion block.